# dropdown menu floating left side and navigation menu is going blur

Tags: html, css

I am making website for the first time. I am having issues with dropdown menu. It is going towards left side. Please help me with the code so that it should be right below the navigation menu and it should be visible while hovering on it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my CSS code:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:10px 2px 10px 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;    /* To keep navigation menu fixed*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 99.21%;
    height: 77px;
    z-index:1000;  /* To bring ul above image.*/
}

ul li a { /*Link Decoration*/
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    display: block;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: What is your HTML code and may you provide a picture how it is and/or should be.

Comment: I am not able to add a screenshot since i its over 2mb. But nothing has been changed by replacing those things. Instead of going left,now it is going right. But I want the sub menu right below the parent menu.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `left:0` to `right:0` and `float` to `right`:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:10px 2px 10px 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;    /* To keep navigation menu fixed*/
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 99.21%;
    height: 77px;
    z-index:1000;  /* To bring ul above image.*/
}
li {
    float: right;
}
```